# Why does Localization not work in my Django project?

Tags: python, django, localization

I'm working on a project that it's default language is not English. I have done the following settings:
1. I created a locale folder in root directory.
2. Then added the following code in settings.py:
`LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)`
3. At the end I run this command in cmd:
`django-admin makemessages -l fa`
but the language files weren't created.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: did you set `LANGUAGES` in the settings.py?

Comment: NO. I Haven't. Do you mean LANGUAGE_CODE?

Comment: i mean https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#languages